# How to specify the path which is to be tested using iozone?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, iops, iozone

I have a freebsd install which has ufs filesystem. Inside freebsd i have created a zpool in raidz1. Now i want to perform iozone test on zfs but i am not able to understand how to specify that iozone test on the zpool not the base filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

`iozone` will operate in the current directory by default. If you wish to test your ZFS pool, change directories to the relevant directory containing the pol or child filesystems, then execute `iozone`.